# Dynamically add form & its contents in HTML & jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, frames

JavaScript:

```
$('.addTable').live('click', function () {
    var appendTxt = "<table id='tab1'>  
                <tr><td><input type='text'   name='input1' /></td><td><input type='text'   name='input2' /></td>
                    <td><input type='button' class='addRow' value='Add Row' /></td></tr></table>";
    $("table:last").after(appendTxt);
});

$('.addRow').live('click', function () {
    var appendTxt = "<td><input type='text'name='input1' /></td><td><input 
                type='text'name='input2' /></td><td><input type='button' class='addRow' value='Add Row'/></td> ";
    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="input1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="input2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" class="addTable" value="addTable" />
```

When I hit "add row" button, I get a new row dynamically. When I hit "add table" button I get a new table.

But after this when I hit "add row" in both new as well as old table, I get a row added in the last added table because I have put `$("tr:last").after(appendTxt)`
so it appends in the latest `<tr>` which is present in the latest table.

Is there a better way to do this so that when I hit "new table", I can add a row to the respective tables?

Comment: What are you expecting exactly ?

Comment: i want to add a new table when i click on add table. this table t1 will have row1. when i hit add row button, it must add a row only in table t1. similarly for table t2 must have its own rows.

Comment: Your code is also re-using the same ID every time a table is added. IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment above.

Change:

```
$("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
```

To:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr:last').after(appendTxt);
```

I assume your Add Row button exists in each table where you add a new row.